# Convert tuple containing tuple into dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

**Set-up**

I have a list containing tuples, each which contains a tuple.

Part of the list,

```
l = [ ('E', ('1058GK', '1058GK')),
      ('K', ('1058GL', '1058GN')),
      ('E', ('1058GP', '1058HC')),
      ('K', ('1058HD', '1058LT'))]
```

---

**Problem**

I want to convert `l` to a dictionary such that,

```
d = {'E': ['1058GK','1058GK','1058GP','1058HC'],
     'K': ['1058GL','1058GN','1058HD','1058LT']}
```

How would I go about?

---

**Tried**

`d = {k:v for k,v in l}` brings me close, but this would create,

```
d = {'E': ('1058GP','1058HC'),
     'K': ('1058HD','1058LT')}
```

Comment: Have you done anything so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use  [`setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=setdefault#dict.setdefault):

```
d = {}
for key, lst in l:
    d.setdefault(key, []).extend(lst)

# results in
# d = {'E': ['1058GK', '1058GK', '1058GP', '1058HC'], 
#      'K': ['1058GL', '1058GN', '1058HD', '1058LT']}
```

if the `key` is not in the dictionary already, it will be added, containing an empty list. the list is then extended with the elements in the corresponding tuples.

---

or you could use a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)

for key, lst in l:
    d[key].extend(lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
l = [ 
    ('E', ('1058GK', '1058GK')),
    ('K', ('1058GL', '1058GN')),
    ('E', ('1058GP', '1058HC')),
    ('K', ('1058HD', '1058LT'))
]
res = dict()
for elem in l:
    res[elem[0]] = res.get(elem[0], []) + list(elem[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

As the keys in your original list can occur several times, it is best to loop through your list. You can go through your list element wise and right away split the outer tuple into key-element pairs like so:

```
l = [ ('E', ('1058GK', '1058GK')),
      ('K', ('1058GL', '1058GN')),
      ('E', ('1058GP', '1058HC')),
      ('K', ('1058HD', '1058LT'))]
mydict = {}
for key, tup in l:
    try:
        mydict[key]+=list(tup)
    except KeyError:
        mydict[key]=list(tup)

print(mydict)
```

the try-except block makes sure that the different keys really exist within mydict and if they don't, creates them accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is ok

```
d = {k:[] for (k, v) in l}
for (k, v) in l:
    d[k] += list(v)
print(d)
```

First it allocates a dictionary of empty lists. Then is iterates over the elements of `l` casting tuples to lists and merging them with respect to the keys `k`.